# Geopandas: dataframe to geodataframe with different espg code

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, coordinate-systems, pyproj

I have a  dataframe (df2): wherein x,y are specified in rd new `epsg:28992` coordinates.

```
            x           y      z     batch_nr  batch_description
0  117298.377  560406.392  0.612         5800   PRF Grasland (l)
1  117297.803  560411.756  1.015                                
2  117296.327  560419.840  1.580                                
3  117295.470  560425.716  2.490                                
4  117296.875  560429.976  4.529
```

more CRS info:

```
# def CRS, used in geopandas
from pyproj import CRS
crs_rd = CRS.from_user_input(28992)
crs_rd
```

```
<Derived Projected CRS: EPSG:28992>
Name: Amersfoort / RD New
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- X[east]: Easting (metre)
- Y[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: Netherlands - onshore, including Waddenzee, Dutch Wadden Islands and 12-mile offshore coastal zone.
- bounds: (3.2, 50.75, 7.22, 53.7)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: RD New
- method: Oblique Stereographic
Datum: Amersfoort
- Ellipsoid: Bessel 1841
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

How can I convert df2 to a geodatafame where the geometry is set as CRS: EPSG 28992?

Comment: Does `df2.to_crs('epsg:28992')` work?

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple case of using **GeoPandas** constructor with `crs` parameter and `points_from_xy()`

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import io

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""            x           y      z     batch_nr  batch_description
0  117298.377  560406.392  0.612         5800   PRF Grasland (l)
1  117297.803  560411.756  1.015                                
2  117296.327  560419.840  1.580                                
3  117295.470  560425.716  2.490                                
4  117296.875  560429.976  4.529"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df2["x"], df2["y"], df2["z"]), crs="epsg:28992")

gdf
```

#### output

|  | x | y | z | batch_nr | batch_description | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 117298 | 560406 | 0.612 | 5800 | PRF Grasland (l) | POINT Z (117298.377 560406.392 0.612) |
| 1 | 117298 | 560412 | 1.015 | nan |  | POINT Z (117297.803 560411.756 1.015) |
| 2 | 117296 | 560420 | 1.58 | nan |  | POINT Z (117296.327 560419.84 1.58) |
| 3 | 117295 | 560426 | 2.49 | nan |  | POINT Z (117295.47 560425.716 2.49) |
| 4 | 117297 | 560430 | 4.529 | nan |  | POINT Z (117296.875 560429.976 4.529) |